# How to clone directly from Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, git, magento-cloud

I have a project and I don't have access to the Bitbucket repo but I have master access to the Magento Cloud project.

How could I clone the project to my local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run this command below, dont' forget to use your project id and the environment name.

```
magento-cloud get bkyvkcoafe -e production
```

But if you're not able to do it you can clone using this another command.

```
git clone bkyvkcoafe5@git.us-3.magento.cloud:bkyvkcoafe5.git
```

Comment: I am trying to clone it on another server, I copied git command and run on my server it says `git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository`. Then I tried using CLI but it ask to login using `magento-cloud login` I run this command and it ask to open url in browser and login `http://127.0.0.1:5000` but this is localhost url

Answer (score 1):

After you log in to Magento cloud, go to your project from the top menu. On the left panel, you will the environments/branches available for the project. Click on the environment you want to clone.

After that, you will be able to see the CLI/GIT command to clone the repo from the cloud directly. Please see the below image.

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.